# $operator and atomic vector - where to put my data.frame code

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I've read through a few answers on how to solve this by creating a "data frame" instead of using a vector, however i'm not sure exactly where I would put it in the below code block; please help!!

What I am trying to do - this is for a uni assignment. This question is about recording statistics from the means of each region.
Explanation. on the means from each region: Create a new data frame based on the means from each region. make sure they combine male and female values to get age distributions

```
region_list <- unique(abs_data$region)

means_vec <- rep(0, times=length(region_list))
for (i in seq(1, length(region_list))){
  region_df <- abs_data %>% filter(region==region_list[i])
  # weights
  weights = region_df$population/sum(region_list$population)
  # mean
  sample_values_mean = sum(weights * region_list$age)
  means_vec[i] <- sample_values_mean
}


SAMPLE DATA;

structure(list(region = c("SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
"SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
"SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
"SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184"), 
    age = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", 
    "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
    "M", "F", "M", "F"), population = c(114L, 95L, 88L, 107L, 
    122L, 120L, 123L, 125L, 114L, 117L, 140L, 147L, 131L, 137L, 
    127L, 130L, 139L, 157L, 149L, 161L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to work with? This would make it easier to help you.

Comment: [1] "Dimensions: 56000, 4"
[1] "Column names and types"
[1] "     region character"
[1] "     age integer"
[1] "     gender character"
[1] "     population integer"
[1] "Number of unique regions: 500"
[1] "Minimum Age: 0"
[1] "Maximum Age: 55"
[1] "Age Bin Size: 1"

Comment: Oops sorry this is my first coding course ever - I am trying to figure out how to best send through the sample data

Comment: @bstrain I have updated with some sample data - does this help?

Comment: Sample data is best shared in a way that we can copy/paste into our R session directly. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 . Use `dput(head(abs_data, 20))` and add it in your post. Also please explain what you are trying to do, there are defintely better ways to do this instead of `for` loop.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you so much you are so helpful, i've edited the post to make those additions. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: To get mean of `population` in each `region` you can do `aggregate(population~region, df, mean)` To get mean of `population` in each `region` and `gender` do `aggregate(population~region + gender, df, mean)`

Comment: I meant `aggregate(population~region, abs_data, mean)` and `aggregate(population~region + gender, abs_data, mean)`

Answer (score 0):

What you've done with the line:

```
region_list <- unique(abs_data$region)
```

Is create a *list* called region_list. The unique(...) function returns the same datatype that you give to it, which makes it seem like you'd get a dataframe back, but because you called abs_data$region (a list) you get a list back.

This is solved by changing the above code to:

```
region_list <- as.data.frame(unique(abs_data$region))
```

Which coerces it back into a dataframe so you can then use the $ operator.

Here is your solution:

```
library(dplyr)

abs_data <- structure(list(region = c("SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
                                      "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
                                      "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", 
                                      "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184", "SSC21184"), 
                           age = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                   6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", 
                                                                           "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
                                                                           "M", "F", "M", "F"), population = c(114L, 95L, 88L, 107L, 
                                                                                                               122L, 120L, 123L, 125L, 114L, 117L, 140L, 147L, 131L, 137L, 
                                                                                                               127L, 130L, 139L, 157L, 149L, 161L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
                                                                                                               ), class = "data.frame")
region_list <- as.data.frame(unique(abs_data$region))

means_vec <- rep(0, times=length(region_list))
for (i in seq(1, length(region_list))){
  region_df <- abs_data %>% filter(region==region_list[i])
  # weights
  weights = region_df$population/sum(region_list$population)
  # mean
  sample_values_mean = sum(weights * region_list$age)
  means_vec[i] <- sample_values_mean
}
```